# Creating an new instance of a C++ class, results a duplicate

Tags: c++, oop, singly-linked-list

I'm new to C++. I'm trying to implement a LinkedList, for which I created two classes `Node` and `LinkedList`.

I created some test functions. One to test the `Node` creation and another to test the `isEmpty` function from `LinkedList`. However, when I try to test them. What's created in 'testNode()`ends up being in the same Node I create inside`LinkedList`as`head`.

This may be trivial question, however as a newcomer to C++ this concept is still no clear to me. I'd like to know why it is referring to the same instance created previously.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
    private:
        int data;
        int next;

    public:

        int getData(){return data;}
        void setData(int new_data) {data = new_data;}

        int getNext(){return next;}
        void setNext(int new_next) {next = new_next;}

};


class LinkedList
{
    Node head;
    Node head2;

    public:

        bool isEmpty()
        {
            if (head.getData() == 0) {return true;}
            return false;
        }

};

void testNode()
{
    Node aNode;
    aNode.setData(15);
    aNode.setNext(23);

    assert (aNode.getData() == 15);
    assert (aNode.getNext() == 23);
}

void testEmptyLinkedList()
{
    LinkedList ll;
    assert (ll.isEmpty() == true);
}
```

Comment: You never initialize `data` or `next` in the constructor resulting in undefined behavior when you try reading values from them.

Comment: It's always good to practice and learn new stuff and experience the problems that arise from a particular design but keep in mind that you should avoid linked lists in C/C++. There exists a video from the creator of C++ language himself explaining why you should avoid this design and use `std::vector` instead. look it up!

Comment: @Barracuda thanks for the info. I'm doing as part of the learning process of C++. I will keep this in mind for when I'm working. Good Info!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your data.

```
int data = 0;
int next = 0;
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70ae52083ea862f9)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class Node {
  private:
    int data = 0;
    int next = 0;

  public:
    int getData() { return data; }
    void setData(int new_data) { data = new_data; }

    int getNext() { return next; }
    void setNext(int new_next) { next = new_next; }
};

class LinkedList {
    Node head;
    Node head2;

  public:
    bool isEmpty() {
        if (head.getData() == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

void testNode() {
    Node aNode;
    aNode.setData(15);
    aNode.setNext(23);

    assert(aNode.getData() == 15);
    assert(aNode.getNext() == 23);
}

void testEmptyLinkedList() {
    LinkedList ll;
    assert(ll.isEmpty() == true);
}

int main() {
    testEmptyLinkedList();
}
```

Comment: what if I have a Node which is whose data is actually 0 and the next Node is also a 0. (Not sure if this is possible under the idea behind LinkedLists). Would, in that case, a way to initialize it to NULL?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to implement LinkList, each node of the list should contain the address of the next one.

So "next" shoud be declared as a pointer to a Node. Same for the first node of the list.

```
class Node {
private:
     int data;
     Node *next;
     ....
};

class LinkedList {
private:
     Node *head;
     ...
};
```